# Java image scaling function has some kind of memory leak

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, game-engine, bufferedimage

Hello once again stackoverflow, so I am working on my latest project, an oil-tycoon game, after being inspired by a movie. It involves an overworld map which you can zoom in, and for that I have a function which scales the images to a certain size depending on how much you scrolled. I am used to C++ where you manually free up memory so please go easy on me as I don't fully understand the garbage collector and what not, English also isn't my native language.

The function is this (partly from stackoverflow, I love you guys):

```
public void scale(int dWidth, int dHeight) {

    Image newImg = this.baseImg.getScaledInstance(dWidth, dHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    // Create a buffered image with transparency
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(newImg.getWidth(null), newImg.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(newImg, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();
    this.img.flush();
    this.img = bimage;
    bimage.flush();
    newImg.flush();

}
```

This function is part of a class, Bitmap, which has a BufferedImage member variable, img. This member variable is used to actually draw the images on screen. However upon testing my new scaling functionality, I noticed memory usage skyrocketed as the function was called. Moreover, the memory wasn't actually freed up. I tested it, and without the calls to the scale function, memory usage is stable at around ~200MB, but once I start calling this function (for one image only, called every time a MouseWheelMoved event fires) it skyrockets once you scroll. Every scroll increases the memory usage by a lot, and it never goes back down. I already added the flush calls, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Neither does setting the local variables to null. I suspect there is some kind of memory leak in this function.

So my question to you guys: can anyone confirm this? Does anybody see a memory leak in this function? If not, what else could be causing this ridiculous increase in memory usage upon calling this function? I just want to stress again that I'm 100% sure this function is the cause of it.

I can post more code if needed (for instance the actual calls to the function), but I omitted it for simplicity for the time being.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Added extra code, as requested.

Lets dive down this rabbit hole, from top to bottom.

First off, I have a class, GameWindow, which extends JFrame. It has a MouseWheelListener like this:

```
    this.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0) {

            double scrollAmount  = arg0.getPreciseWheelRotation();

            curMapScale -= ((double)scrollAmount * 0.1);
            // Reset zooming
            if(curMapScale <= 0)
            {
                curMapScale = 1.0;
            }



        }

    });
```

My game loop is as such (noobish, I know):

```
private void gameLoop()
{

    boolean abort = false;

    long curTime = 0;
    long prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(!abort)
    {
        curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // 500ms for debugging the scaling issue
        if(curTime - prevTime > (500))
        {
            prevTime = curTime;
            wGame.render();
        }

    }
}
```

wGame is the GameWindow object, and it's render function is like this:

```
public void render()
{
    mainPanel.updateGame();
    mainPanel.render();
}
```

mainPanel is an object of GraphicsPanel, a class that extends JPanel.
It's updateGame() function:

```
public void updateGame()
{
    em.update();
}
```

and it's render function:

```
public void render()
{
    this.repaint();
}
```

And finally it's scaleEntities() function

```
public void scaleEntities()
{
    // Deleted scaling of all entities except the map in order to debug the scaling issue
    em.scaleMap(getWidth() * GameWindow.curMapScale, getHeight() * GameWindow.curMapScale );    
}
```

em is an object of the class EntityManager, a class which contains ArrayLists with every entity in the game world. It's update function goes like this:

```
public void update()
{
    // Loop through all generic entities en update them (entityList is empty  
    // for the moment
    for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++)
    {
        entityList.get(i).update();
    }
    // Loop through all pointsOfInterests, which exist only on the overworld
    // also empty for the moment
    for(int i = 0; i < pointsOfInterest.size(); i++)
    {
        pointsOfInterest.get(i).update();
    }
    // Update the current map (note the update() function isn't actually used yet, it will be used to update an entities position if it has a velocity
    mapList.get(curMap).update();

    // Stuff pertaining to Window Resizing, which is irrelevant right now
    GameWindow.resetOffset();
    GameWindow.hasMouseDragged = false;
}
```

and it's scaleMap() function goes like this:

```
public void scaleMap(double width, double height)
{
    mapList.get(curMap).scale((int)Math.ceil(width), (int)Math.ceil(height));
}
```

the call to scale in this function is passed down directly to the Bitmap object of the map. The scale function we started out with is thus called.

Last but not least, the paintComponent() function of the GraphicsPanel class, where the objects actually get drawn:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    em.render(g2d);
}
```

The EntityManagers render function:

```
public void render(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    // Only draw the map for debugging purposes
    mapList.get(curMap).draw(g2d);

//  for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++)
//  {
//      entityList.get(i).draw(g2d);
//  }
//  for(int i = 0; i < pointsOfInterest.size(); i++)
//  {
//      pointsOfInterest.get(i).draw(g2d);
//  }
}
```

And the maps draw function:

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    BufferedImage temp = bitm.getSource();

    g2d.drawImage(temp, (int)this.loc.getX(), (int)this.loc.getY(), null);

    temp.flush();

}
```

bitm is obviously the Bitmap member of the map, and it's getSource() function goes like this:

```
public BufferedImage getSource()
{
    return this.img;
}
```

This should be all relevant code. Does anybody see where the memory leak might come from? I have a feeling the newImg and bimage variables in the Bitmaps scale function aren't properly deleted.

Thanks in advance, once again!

Comment: Add more source code, e.g. of the `Bitmap` class and the class code making the calls on event will help put the problem into better perspective. I have a feeling it has to do with the `this.img = bimage;` but I cannot help/answer as I feel I do not have a complete enough question to answer. cheers

Comment: Just added some extra code, still think the problem lies within the scale function, however. I tried commenting out the this.img = bimage line and the memory usage rose even faster when scrolling then before. Definitely not the problem.